# PowerBi DAX - Variable (CONCATENAX) in operator "IN"

Tags: powerbi

Exists a form to do a variable Concatenax in operator "IN" on dax?

example:

Max value =
VAR SUC = CONCANATEX(FILTERS (TABLE[COLUMN]; TABLE[COLUMN]; ";")

VAR SOLUTION = CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE[COLUMN2]; TABLE[COLUMN] IN {SUC})

RETURN SOLUTION

---

my code return nothing when have 2 values in SUC.

Thanks.

Comment: In first place, why you want to use concatenax when you can just put Table as filter into your  Calculate. What do you want to achieve? Add some data example

Comment: hello,

i need to do a multiples calculations in other columns..

i need to do it... you have any idea?

i put a imagem of code in post...

Comment: What do you plan to show, it is better to put the sample data and expected output

Comment: @MSS, add a sample of your data and your desired result.  Currently, we are unsure what you try to achive